# Assigning custom method to on_touch_down etc. in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm writing what is ultimately to be a mobile game app using Kivy. Given the capabilities of the framework - being able to separate form and function - I'm attempting to do most, if not all, of the design of my GUI within a .kv file using the Kivy language. This works great as far as crafting a layout, but getting touch event handlers to work correctly is proving quite challenging. What I'm attempting to do is this:

Python:

```
from kivy import require
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

require("1.9.1")

class gameScreen(FloatLayout):

    def move_scatter(self, sender):
        self.ids.moveArea.x = sender.text

    def pc_move(self, touch, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Goodbye')
        # self.ids.protagonist.pos = (self.x + )

class GameApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return gameScreen()

class MoveBox(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Pc(Image):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

Kivy Code:

```
<gameScreen>:

    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 20

    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: (root.width, root.height)
            source: 'bliss.jpg'

    Pc:
        id: protagonist

    TextInput:
        id: debugOut
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 50
        text: 'Hello'

    BoxLayout:
        id: moveArea
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 200
        on_touch_down: root.pc_move()
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .2, .2, .2, .5
            Rectangle:
                pos: (self.x + root.width - self.width, self.y)
                size: self.size


<Pc>
    source:'voolf.png'
    pos_hint: {'top': .9}
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 300, 300
```

When I try this, I get:

```
TypeError: pc_move() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

This obviously make sense, as I am calling the pc_move() method without passing an argument. I know that the *easiest* way around this issue is just to create the BoxLayout in my Python code and define the on_touch_down method there, but as stated, I'm trying to keep my GUI and functionality separate.

The question is, how do I get the 'touch' parameter to pass as it would if I were to create the widget in Python code? Alternatively, am I just chasing a white whale? Does the event handling have to be done in a widget created in the Python code?

Comment: I apologize, this app is pretty rough. There's a lot of debug functionality in there, as this is my first foray into mobile development. Please focus on the specifics of the question, and try to overlook that this app essentially does nothing in its current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confess I've never used Kivy, but the [documentation for on_touch_down](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.on_touch_down) indicates it receives a `touch` parameter.

The [docs also mention](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords) that `args` keyword *is available in on_ callbacks*.

Putting these two together, you should be able to pass your touch parameter to python via:

```
on_touch_down: root.pc_move(args[1])
```

[I'm not positive that it will be the #1 element in `args[]`, but some of the examples seem to indicate that]

Comment: That was the quickest, most helpful response I've received in a very long time. This solved my problem very nicely. Thank you very much for weighing in.